# Why a mode on Minkowsky SpaceTime becomes two modes on Rindler Spacetime

Tags: reference-frames, quantum-entanglement, unruh-effect

----I am a student on Quantum Computing--- For the whole undertanding of

*"Tetrapartite entanglement measures of GHZ
state with uniform acceleration" by Qiang Dong. https://doi.org/10.1088/1402-4896/ab2111*

I read this equation

> |0>Minkowski = cos ri |0> RindlerI · |0> RindlerII + sen ri |1>
> RindlerI · |1> RindlerII
>
> |1>Minkowski = |1> RindlerI · |0> RindlerII

But in spite I am reading around this article and studing about QFT I still don't catch the idea.  I think the explanaition is on Bololuvob Transformations but I haven't found enough information.

**IMAGE A**

[image: Transformation betwwwn Minkowski and Rindler Spacetime]

Seeking on the web I found

*"Teleportation with a uniformly accelerated partner by Alsing"     arXiv:quant-ph/0302179*

**IMAGE B**

[image: Formula of the celebrated result of Davis and Unruh]

Where I find the same expression but less clear for me.

Might you help me?